# Heroku : Cannot find module 'pg'?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, module

I tried deploying on heroku and had error

Comment: What's in your procfile?

Comment: I just got home from the park. Are your node modules in the same directory as your entry file? /node_modules/ in the same directory as app.js for example.

Comment: Yes thank you :) The only other thing I can see is moving "pg": "^8.5.1", into dependencies since it's currently under devDependencies. Make sure you run an 'npm run build'

Comment: Great! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

So the file structure would be:

/app

----app.js

----node_modules/

It is also necessary to move pg from devDependencies into Dependencies and run npm run build.